# PHP: Remove whitespace from money_format

Tags: php, money-format

I'm using money_format to generate a string like `1,23€`.

At first I'm using

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'de_DE.utf8');
```

If I use this:

```
money_format('%.2n', $1.23);
```

I'm getting this:

```
1,23 €
```

But I would like to get this:

```
1,23€
```

(without whitespace).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use PHP `str_replace`

```
str_replace(' €','€','1,23 €')
```

or

```
str_replace(' ','','1,23 €')
```

`str_replace` function replaces some characters with some other characters in a string

```
str_replace(find,replace,string)
```